# Set CommandParameter to currently tapped item on a ListBox (WP7)

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-7

I want to set command parameter to currently selected item on a ListBox.

**XAML:**

```
<!--<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Places}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlace, Mode=TwoWay}">-->
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Places}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListBoxClick}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                (...)
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

**C#** (part of ViewModel code exposing the ListBoxClick command)

```
public RelayCommand ListBoxClick { get; set; }

ListBoxClick = new RelayCommand((o) => {
    //model is always null
    var model = o as BasicModel;

    SelectedPlace = model;
});
```

I added appropriate references, and namespace:

```
xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
```

The problem is that in action called by `RelayCommand` object the `o` parameter is always null.

**UPDATE**

**C#** code for `SelectedPlace` property

```
public BasicModel SelectedPlace {
            get {
                return _selectedPlace;
            }
            set {
                _selectedPlace = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPlace");
            }
        }
```

When I use this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Places}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlace, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

everything works fine if I click ListBoxItem for the first time, but when I click on a selected ListBoxItem nothing happens, because selection doesn't change. I need to be able to detect item click in both situations.

Comment: `Places` type is `BasicModel`?

Comment: Yes, Places is an `ObservableCollection<BasicModel>`

Comment: Please explain (in an edit to your question) exactly what your requirement actually is. Forget `ICommand`s and `SelectedItem`s for a minute and tell us what you're actually trying to achieve with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out an ugly way to achieve my goal.

**XAML**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Places}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPlace, Mode=TwoWay}">
```

**C#** (ViewModel)

```
private bool _placeSelected;

public BasicModel SelectedPlace {
    get {
        return _selectedPlace;
    }
    set {
        _placeSelected = true;
        _selectedPlace = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPlace");
    }
}

ListBoxClick = new RelayCommand((o) => {
    if (!_placeSelected) {
        SelectedPlace = _selectedPlace;
    }
    else {
        _placeSelected = false;
    }
});
```

This way `RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPlace");` will be called in both cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Places}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListBoxClick}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={
x:Type ListBox}}}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            (...)
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

If that doesn't work, try changing the `Binding` to this:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
```

---

UPDATE >>>

Oh sorry, I didn't see that you were using Windows Phone 7. As an alternative, try adding a property into your code behind/view model that binds to the `ListBox.SelectedItem` property:

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Places}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}" ... />
```

Then you should be able to do this:

```
ListBoxClick = new RelayCommand(() => {
    SelectedPlace = SelectedItem;
});
```

---

UPDATE 2 >>>

I don't know if Windows Phone 7 supports the `Binding.ElementName` property, but if it does, try this:

```
<ListBox Name="ListBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Places}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Tap">
            <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ListBoxClick}" 
CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementNameListBox}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            (...)
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: When I use the second solution `o` is still null, when I use the first one, I get: `The property 'AncestorType' does not exist on the type 'RelativeSource' in the XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'`, `The type 'x:Type' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built.`, `The property 'AncestorType' was not found in type 'RelativeSource'.`. Namespaces I use in this view are as follows:

Comment: `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"`
`xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`
`xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"`
`xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"`
`xmlns:i="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"`

Comment: I actually have that property, and it's called SelectedPlace :). Maybe I should explain why I'm using triggers instead of just using the SelectedItem property. With the later everything works fine if I click ListBoxItem for the first time, but when I click on a selected ListBoxItem nothing happens, because selection doesn't change. I need to be able to detect item click in both situations.